# jQuery Resize Not Firing and Dropdown Missing

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, resize, window

This script is for a unordered list with dropdown menus. The second part controls a containing element for when viewing on tablet/mobile devices. The problem I am having is that the window resize event isn't firing consistently across projects.

Also, when going from a small window size browser, to a larger size, the dropdowns are all of a sudden unable to break free from the containing Nav element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.primary li').click(function () {
    var a = this;
    if ($('ul', this).is(':visible')) {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(function () {
            $(a).removeClass('active')
        })
    } else {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active');
        $('ul', this).slideDown();
        $(a).addClass('active')
    }
});
$('body').click(function (a) {
    if (!$(a.target).is('a')) {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
    }
});
$(function () {
    $('.mobile-nav').click(function (e) {
        $('.primary').slideToggle(150, "swing");
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('ul.drop').slideUp();
        $('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
    });
})
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="mobile-nav">Navigation</div>
        <ul class="primary">
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="has-drop">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="has-drop" href="#link">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.clear { 
clear:both; }
.nav {
display:block;
width:100%; 
background:#222; }

.mobile-nav {
visibility: hidden;
padding: 0;
height: 0px; }

ul.primary {
background: #222;
list-style: none;
height: 45px;
min-width: 350px;
position: relative;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
float: right; }

ul.primary li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    max-width: 100%; }

    ul.primary li a, ul.drop li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none; }

ul.drop li a { padding: 5px; }

ul.primary li a:hover, ul.drop li a:hover { background: #444; }

ul.primary li, ul.drop li { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

ul.primary li.active > a { background: #444; }

a.has-drop { cursor: pointer; }

a.has-drop span {
    margin: -8px 0 0 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    float: right;
    background: url("drop-caret.png") no-repeat center right; }

li.active > a.has-drop span {
margin: -8px 0 0 5px;
width: 10px;
height: 5px;
float: right;
background: url("drop-caret-up.png") no-repeat center right; }

ul.drop {
display: none;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-width: 100%;
width: auto;
width: auto;
list-style: none;
background: #242424;
border: none; }

ul.drop li {
    float: none;
    font-weight: normal; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
nav {
display: block;
width: 100%;
border: 0px solid white;
padding: 10px 0; }

.mobile-nav {
visibility: visible;
height: auto;
margin: 0 5px;
padding: 10px 0;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
background: url("mobile-nav.png") no-repeat center right; }

ul.primary {
float: none;
display: none;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }

ul.primary li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444; }

    ul.primary li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }

ul.drop li, ul.primary li.active { border-bottom: none; }

ul.drop li a {
text-indent: 15px;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: italic; }

a.has-drop span {
margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
width: 10px;
height: 5px;
float: right;
background: url("drop-caret.png") no-repeat center right; }

li.active > a.has-drop span {
margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
width: 10px;
height: 5px;
float: right;
background: url("drop-caret-up.png") no-repeat center right; }
}
```

Comment: Do this example demonstrates your code? http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/dWVsU/

Comment: Yes it does, I am comparing it to my code so I can learn what I did wrong.

Comment: In fact, I am not able to see any error in it. I just copied and paste your code! Check your jquery version.

Comment: It's loaded by Wordpress, and version 1.7.2. It seems to be working now on my site, i think the problem might have lain within my declaration of $j = jQuery.noConflict();, which I altered to read "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();" once I implemented the code from your jsFiddle code.

And then of course changed all occurrences of $ to $j.

But I am still running into the issue of when a user expands a menu in the mobile view in their browser, once expanded, the menu will not expand outside of the containing element. Although on the jsFiddle, this does not occur. I must have a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Well done! congratulations.

Comment: Seems my ul.drop element on my site, is receiving a overflow: hidden from element.style in Chrome. Yet in the jsFiddle, it is not being given this property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20192/discussion-between-aj-troxell-and-ss)